# Unexpected behavior of Z1 and Sky motes in Cooja simulation in DODAG formation

Tags: contiki, cooja, contiki-ng

I was exploring the Contiki Cooja simulator (with Contiki NG) and experimenting with a UDP server and several UDP clients (from examples/rpl-udp) with different mote types when I noticed something I didn't expect.

*When I set the motes as type z1/sky, almost all client motes send DAOs only to the server.* In fact the DODAG ends with a star topology (with several clients remaining isolated due to small neighbour table size in sky mote).

However, in the case of cooja motes, this does not happen; clients send DAOs to other clients as well.

[Pattern of DAOs in a scenario with z1 motes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGKME.png)

Is this intended and default?
If it is the default, then why? How can this behaviour be altered?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum routing table and neighbor table sizes are limited by compilation constants in Contiki-NG. On Sky and Z1 they are particularly small as these platforms do not have a lot RAM, and can cause some issues with RPL.

For instance, on Z1 the following defines are set. The neighbor table size of 8 in particular is much too small for many networks.

```
#define NBR_TABLE_CONF_MAX_NEIGHBORS    8
#define NETSTACK_MAX_ROUTE_ENTRIES      8
```

For platforms that do not set them explicitly, these constants are 16 and 16 respectively.

On Cooja they are much larger:

```
#define NBR_TABLE_CONF_MAX_NEIGHBORS    300
#define NETSTACK_MAX_ROUTE_ENTRIES      300
```

Comment: I understand and agree with your point. To make my question clearer, please refer to the attached image.

What I cannot understand is why, say node 6, sends a DAO to the root (node 1) and not to node 2, 4, or 7. Why are the clients behaving like leaves?

Comment: @ShivanshM DAOs are sent to the root node if non-storing RPL mode is used and to parent nodes if storing RPL is used. Could there be this difference in your own configuration, for the different platforms?

Comment: I redid the experiment with a fresh installation of contiki-ng and found the same results. I only added a project-conf.h to the rpl-udp examples directory, which enabled the logging of RPL messages.

Comment: My installation was unable to checkout a commit in the following:

`shivansh@shivanshm:~/contiki-ng$ git diff arch/cpu/arm/CMSIS
diff --git a/arch/cpu/arm/CMSIS b/arch/cpu/arm/CMSIS
index a65b7c9a3..e513dbdb2 160000
--- a/arch/cpu/arm/CMSIS
+++ b/arch/cpu/arm/CMSIS
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit a65b7c9a3e6502127fdb80eb288d8cbdf251a6f4
+Subproject commit e513dbdb2b0bfb839f6374b8a5c5d037fab6c0ce-dirty
`

Comment: The CMSIS submodule is ARM specific. It isn't relevant to any of the issues you're experiencing. If you think there is a bug with that submodule, please report to Contiki-NG issue tracker.

Comment: About the initial problem, I see your point. Sorry that it's not working as you expected. I think I will leave the answer anyway, even if it did not help you. Someone else may experience a similar problem and find this solution useful.

Comment: I was trying to use z1/sky as they allow RSSI detection due to CC2420. Can we achieve that with cooja motes? If so, is there a quick reference for how to achieve that?     Thanks a lot for your really quick responses. [ I will soon delete this entire comment as it is not related to the discussion ]

Comment: yes, I see. Last packet's RSSI should be somewhat ok on COoja motes, but continous signal level monitoring via RSSI will not work at all at the moment. There is a recent PR that should improve things - but not sure if its enough. https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/pull/1661

Comment: Wow, as of now I am looking for the last packet's RSSI only, will try once it is merged. In case that doesn't work, I will try Contiki 3.0 for my purposes. Thanks